# ROS2 Message generation in python package

Tags: ros, python, ros2, message-generation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have a python package with multiple nodes and I need to send a message from one node to another.
Currently the message type is `from std_msgs.msg import Int16MultiArray`, but I need to add a header to this message. The message contains the encoder values from 3 wheels and are transferred from the `hardware driver node` to the `odom node`. This message should have the frame id `base_link` and must contain the time. So I need a `Int16MultiArrayStamped` or I would call it `EncoderStamped` or something like that.

Now I would like to generate a custom message, but I can't find documentation on how this should work inside a python package. I mean I can just create a new CMake package which just contains the new message type with message generation, but I want this to be self contained, because this belongs to this package.

So my question is: Is it possible to have custom message generation in a python package in ROS2 Foxy?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388826/ros2-message-generation-in-python-package/) by [Darkproduct](https://answers.ros.org/users/52476/darkproduct/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2021-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer : No. You can't generate messages on a ROS2 Foxy python package.

However, since you can still have python nodes on cmake packages, you can define the custom messages on a cmake package and also add your python scripts there, so that you will end up with just one package that contains both the code and the message interface definitions.

Source : [Expanding on ROS 2 interfaces](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Single-Package-Define-And-Use-Interface.html#background)

Similar question : [Define custom messages in python package (ROS2)t](https://answers.ros.org/question/350084/define-custom-messages-in-python-package-ros2/)

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2021-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1